# 8bit params via QProcess

Tags: bash, qt, character-encoding

I have an app that must be launched with ASCII params. It treats them as an array of bytes so it must be ASCII and not UTF-8 etc. The values may be non-latin (so it's not a real ASCII, but any of codepages like CP-1251).
In bash I can launch it as

```
myapp --myparam $'abc...Z\xC0\xC1...\xFF'
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode
I can't find a way to do this with QProcess...
It seems to not use bash and launch processes directly, so I can't use `$'\xnn'` [syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html).
It also doesn't accept params in form other than QString. And there is no way to ask it to do `QString::toLocal8Bit()` before passing params to the app (so I could use `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale()` to spoof UTF-8 with other codepage).

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
1. I've got the right answer below.
2, I've also found that QProcess apply QFile::encodeName() to each arg so the problem may be bypassed with `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to not use bash and launch processes directly

You can call bash from the QProcess and execute it directly: -

```
QString cmd = "bash -c \"myapp --myparam $'abc...Z\xC0\xC1...\xFF'\"";
QProcess proc;
proc.execute(cmd);
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if I get app's stderr via proc.readAllStandardError() in this case?

Comment: I would expect so, but try it and find out.